# MQTT Client does not receive acknowledgments after publishing message to broker

Tags: java, callback, mqtt, publish

My problem is that when i want to respond to an arriveng message i dont get the delivery token back from broker but the message is arrived at the broker. i can see it in the logs. So my question is how to respond with a publish to an incoming message?

This is the way i do and it does not work...

```html
public void setMqttCallback() {

        mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
            @Override
            public void connectionLost(final Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println("Lost connection to Broker because of: " + throwable.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(final String topic, final MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Received on " + topic + ": " + new String(mqttMessage.getPayload()));

                topics = new Topics();

                //Answer to arriving messages (Logic)
                if (topic.equals(topics.getVehicleNavLandmarkInfo(Mqtt.VIN_ID))) {

                    landmarks = new Landmarks();

                    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(landmarks.getLandmarks().getBytes());
                    message.setQos(2);

                    System.out.println("Sending on " + topic + ": " + landmarks.getLandmarks());
                    
                    mqttClient.publish(topics.getBackendNavLandsmarks(Mqtt.VIN_ID), message);
                }

                if (topic.equals(topics.getVehicleNavDestination(Mqtt.VIN_ID))) {

                    routing = new Routing(49.0000, 8.0000, "A");

                    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(routing.getShortestPath().getBytes());
                    message.setQos(2);

                    System.out.println("Sending on " + topic + ": " + routing.getShortestPath());
                    
                    mqttClient.publish(topics.getBackendNavRoute(Mqtt.VIN_ID), message);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(final IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
                System.out.println("Delivered Message: " + iMqttDeliveryToken.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Here is a solution for this problem but i dont quiet understand it. Do i have to create another client and connect it to the broker and than publish with it? It doesnt seams right... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161740/how-to-publish-a-message-while-receiving-on-a-java-mqtt-client-using-eclipse-pah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messageArrived method is blocking, so you cannot then try and publish a message using the same mqttClient connection.  You need to use another thread that has its own connection to the broker.

If it is a one-off situation then you can start a new thread and do everything in it but if your application will be constantly publishing messages to arriving messages then it would be better to start a thread, connect to broker then wait for information to be passed from the messageArrived method.

Comment: Do you have code snippets for this? I think thats one of a normal situation but it is nowhere discribed...

Comment: thanks! i used the AsynchClient of the Paho Framework. It works fine now!